# In WPF, is "using System.Windows;" the same as "using Windows.Foundation;" Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, namespaces, windows-store-apps

I am doing a project in WPF C#. I am wondering if "using System.Windows" is the WPF equivalent of the windows store app's "using Windows.Foundation;" As I am having an issue with using Point, Rect, and Size keywords I want to know how to know how to get it working in WPF.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about concepts of a library which might be better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com if it was more specific on what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not exactly. There is a mapping between some WinRT types and .NET types, you can find it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh995050.aspx

Many classes found in .NET's `System` namespace can be found in WinRT's `Windows.Foundation` namespace. The closest match for `System.Windows` would be `Windows.UI.Xaml`, but it doesn't have the exact same types.

Comment: For example I am trying to make something in WPT from a similar win store app. When I use point, size and rect, They are not recognised unless I use "using system.windows". Windows.UI.Xaml is not recognised either, do i have to add it as an assembly in the reference manager?

Comment: @EPOColla, Point and Size are in the Windows.Foundation namespace. You don't need to add any assembly reference. Don't try to find an exact mapping between WPF and WinRT, because there isn't one...

Comment: What I am saying is that all I can use to get point, size and rect working is "System.Windows". is this sufficient for most shapes and other values in WPF?

Comment: @EPOColla, no some types are in System.Windows, others in System.Windows.Controls, or System.Windows.Media, etc. You can use Visual Studio's smart tags to import the correct namespace automatically.